# выбор полей не с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: sql

Есть поля для продуктов, в которых содержатся ключи (для групп)
Нужно выбрать ихние `id` из первой попавшейся записи, без повторений (если у них одинаковые ключи,которые заранее не известны )
Например есть-

```
id key
1  44
2  44
3  66
4  66
5  77
```

Должно получится -> `1,3,5`
пробовал `SELECT`id`FROM`table`GROUP BY`key`HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` - не получилось

Comment: А откуда в вашем примере возьмётся 7?

Comment: ошибся, исправил . В любом случае Ваш ответ помог, пихал лишний count

Answer (score 1):

Сгруппировать по `key`

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` GROUP BY `key`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(id) from table group by key
```